# How to display a PdfPage as image in WPF form using Docotic.pdf.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf

I need to display `PdfPage` of a PDF Document in a WPF form. I am using `Docotic.pdf.dll` and want to stick to it. The `PdfPage.Thumbnail` is also giving me null with all PDFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Docotic.Pdf cannot display PDF files (at least the current version), it can only create them. The PdfPage.Thumbnail refers to the page thumbnail embedded in the PDF file, which usually is missing, this is why the property returns null.

Comment: So can you suggest any other library. My requirement includes display of pages, rotation, also modification and saving of Pdf

Comment: The company I work for develops the PDFView4NET product, a PDF viewer that does all your requirements: http://www.o2sol.com/pdfview4net/overview.htm

Comment: @iPDFdev Docotic.Pdf *never* was a create-only PDF library. Btw, current version can display and print PDF pages. You might want to edit your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just confirmed from Bit Miracle, this feature has been added in Docotic.Pdf 3.4 ([available on their site](http://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/)) and currently it is in beta phase .

Below is the code that will save the image from the Pdf.

```
using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument("your_file.pdf"))
{
    PdfDrawOptions options = PdfDrawOptions.CreateZoom(150);
    options.BackgroundColor = new PdfRgbColor(255, 255, 255); // white background, transparent by default
    options.Format = PdfDrawFormat.Jpeg;
    pdf.Pages[0].Save("result.jpg", options);
}
```

There is also [Draw and print PDF](http://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/help/draw-and-print-pdf.aspx) group of samples that might worth to look into.

Comment: Thanks Lalit, can you provide the link.

Comment: You can ask from Docotic. BTW it might be released in this month.

Comment: New version with support for drawing and printing is now freely available on our site.